# c# capture response from background worker

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm fairly new to this so please go easy on me.  I'm basically starting a background process with a button.  on the same button I want to capture the response.  I know there is a runworkercompleted method which is fine but I want the button click to receive the response.  in this example i've created a dictionary that the task populates with some text.   want the button that launches the thread to be able to read the value out of the dictionary.

here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace background_worker
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Dictionary<Guid , string> _taskdictionary = new Dictionary<Guid, string>();


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //create new task id (guid) and start task
            Guid taskID = Guid.NewGuid();
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(taskID);

            //how do i know when i can grab the result of the threaded job?
            //i know it will be in dictionary but how do i get hold of it
            if (_taskdictionary.ContainsKey(taskID))
                this.Text = _taskdictionary[taskID];
        }


        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            //task will be added to taskdictionary with result

            Guid taskid = (Guid)e.Argument;
            if (!_taskdictionary.ContainsKey(taskid))
                _taskdictionary.Add(taskid, "this is the result");

            #region
            //task will log to file 
            string lines = "this is the result";
            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\result" + taskid.ToString() + ".txt");
            file.WriteLine(lines);
            file.Close();
            #endregion

            e.Result = "complete";
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show((string)e.Result);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Question is not clear, make it clear pls. and any reason for not using "TaskParalellLibrary"?

Comment: not clear? i basically want the button to trigger a background thread and wait for the result of DoWork.

Comment: The point in using a BackgroundWorker is to run some code asynchronously without waiting for the code to end. If you wait for the return of the BackgroundWorker in the button click event, you basically run it synchronously, making the BackgroundWorker obsolete. Can you clarify why you want to use a BackgroundWorker and why you want to use the return in the click event handler? If your sample resembles your real world code, you can also assign the button text in RunWorkerCompleted (maybe you need to use Invoke if this gives an error).

Comment: task is .net4 isn't it? i want to avoid using that at this moment in time.

Comment: Avoiding .NET 4?! Why... It is not even cutting edge and we have .NET 4.5 now. Don't get stuck in the past before you even get going! Nothing wrong with `Task` and get your job done easily enough.

Comment: thanks markus. i was trying to think of a scenario whereby multiple tasks are threaded off  .maybe an example is that 10 people order some food and the orders are threaded off.  The order would still need to link up with the person ordering it.  could the threaded task trigger somekind of event that the person making the order listens for?

Comment: @Belogix Using `Task` without C# 5.0 features doesn't really make this problem any different than using a BGW.  Personally, without the use of `await`, I find the BGW to be quicker/easier to use than `Task` for this type of problem.  If they get more complex than this exact situation, then `Task` can be useful.  It's certainly more general purpose.

Comment: @user2143783 In that case your issue is not forcing the worker's result to be processed within the button click, the issue is that you need to have a different BGW for each request, rather than re-using a single worker for multiple requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the asynchrony features of C# 5.0 to handle this situation, without even using a BackgroundWorker:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = await Task.Run(() => ComputeResult());
    DoStuffWithResult(result);
}
```

Another option, if it's important to have the code written within the button click, is to attach the BGW's event handler's through anonymous methods within the button click:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += ComputeResult;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, args) =>
    {
        DoStuffWithResult(args.Result);
    };
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

If you don't want to do that, then the answer is simply that you can't.  The whole point here is that the button click *needs* to finish before the work is done, so that it can return to its caller (the message loop) so that it can continue processing messages, to prevent the UI from freezing.